# Implementing TextSwitcher

Tags: android

I'm a beginner in android application development.
I want to make an app that is karaoke style, somehow, I can make images change in a specific interval. however, I'm having a problem with regards to text, it doesn't change as the time of the song goes on.
I'm just using textview, but I want to implement TextSwitcher but I really don't know how. I know how to use  ViewFlipper, but viewflipper is for a static interval only. (i think?)
please help me to display the text and make it change with its corresponding time? thank you.
and also is it possible to use TextSwitcher without using arrays? the texts I needed to show are too many to be in an array I think.

here's what I have so far:

```
public class LetItGo extends Activity
{
private ViewFlipper myviewflipper;
TextView t; private String sText;

private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

private Runnable mWaitRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        t.setText(sText);
    }
}; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample);
    myviewflipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper1);
        myviewflipper.setAutoStart(true);
        myviewflipper.setFlipInterval(5000);
        myviewflipper.startFlipping();


        t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1); 

        sText = ("Let It Go / Let Her Go Mash Up" + "\n by Sam Tsui");
        t.setText(sText);       

//1
        sText = ("Let it go, let it go");
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 1000*10);  

//2         
        sText = ("You only need the light when its burning low");
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 6000*10*10);

//3
        sText = ("Let it go, let it go");        
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 9000*10);

//4
        sText = ("You only miss the sun when it starts to snow");        
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 13000*10);  

//5
        sText = ("And here I stand, \n and here I'll stay");
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 17000*10);  

//6         
        sText = ("You only know you love her when you let her go");
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 19000*10);  

//7         
        sText = "The cold never bothered me anyway";
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 25000*10);    

//8         
        sText = ("Staring at the bottom of your glass");
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 34000*10);  

//9         

        sText = ("Hoping one day you'll make a dream last ");
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 37000*10);  

//10  
        sText = ("But dreams come slow");
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 4000*100);  

//11            
        sText = ("and they go so fast");
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 42000*10); 

//12        
        sText = ("You see her when you close your eyes ");
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 47000*10); 

//13            
        sText = ("Maybe one day you'll understand why");
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 5000*100); 

//14        
        sText = "Everything you touch surely dies";
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 54000*10);  

//15        
        sText = ("Don’t let them in, don’t let them see ");
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 62000*10); 

//16            
        sText = ("Be the good guy you always have to be ");
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 65000*10);  

//17            
        sText = ("Conceal, don’t feel, don’t let them know ");
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 69000*10);

//18            
        sText = ("Well, now they know");
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 75000*10);

//19            
        sText = ("Let it go, let it go");
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 78000*10);  

//20            
        sText = ("You only need the light when its burning low");
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 81000*10);

//21
        sText = ("Let it go, let it go");        
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 85000*10);

//22
        sText = ("You only miss the sun when it starts to snow");        
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 88000*10);       

//23
        sText = ("And here I stand, \n and here I'll stay");
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 92000*10);      

//24            
        sText = ("You only know you love her when you let her go");
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 98000*10);   

//25            
        sText = ("The cold never bothered me anyway");
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 104000*10);  

//26            
        sText = ("Let it go,");
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 112000*10);  

//27            
        sText = ("let her go");
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 116000*10);  

//28            
        sText = ("You only need the light when it's burning low");
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 121000*10);  

//29            
        sText = ("You only miss the sun when it starts to snow");
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 124000*10);  

//30                      
        sText = ("You only know you love her when you let her go");
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 127000*10); 

//31            
        sText = ("You only know you've been high when you're feeling low");
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 134000*10);  

//32            
        sText = ("You only hate the road when you’re missin' home");
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 138000*10);

//33            
        sText = ("You only know you love her when you let her go");
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 141000*10); 

//34
        sText = ("And now you know ooooooh");
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 146000*10);

//35
        sText = ("Let it go, let it go");
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 152000*10);

//36            
        sText = ("You only need the light when its burning low");
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 155000*10);

//37
        sText = ("Let it go, let it go");        
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 158000*10);

//38
        sText = ("You only miss the sun when it starts to snow");        
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 162000*10);

//39
        sText = ("And here I stand,");
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 166000*10);


//40            
        sText = ("and here I'll stay");
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 169000*10); 


//41            
        sText = ("You only know you love her when you let her go" + " \n oooooohhhhh...");
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 172000*10); 

//42            
        sText = ("dudududu... ");
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 181000*10);  

//43            
        sText = ("The cold never bothered me anyway");
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 192000*10);  

//44   
        sText = ("Let It Go / Let Her Go Mash Up" + "\n by Sam Tsui");   
        mHandler.postDelayed(mWaitRunnable, 197000*10);


}

}
```

I don't know if i'm doing this correctly actually. I just put things together based on my researches.
In this code, the last sText was displayed and it was not changing. I don't know what to do anymore.
thank you for helping. :)

Comment: Tell me what behavior are you getting and what do you wish for?

Comment: @Campiador as for the pictures yes. but for the text no. the only text that display is the last set which is is the comment 44. it is not changing too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a Handler runs at a moment, it uses the current and latest content of sText available.
All your handlers work great, but they all see the content of sText = ("Let It Go / Let Her Go Mash Up" + "\n by Sam Tsui"), this is the last sText = ("sometext") call; (the 44th)
because the sText = ("something") commands are all executed in the first moment of your application's run-time.

So what to do?

remove all the

```
sText = ("Some Text");
```

except the first one (title of the song).

rewrite your mWaitRunnable as this:

declare an integer for the number of line you are going to print:

```
int lineNumber = 1;

private Runnable mWaitRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        switch (lineNumber) {


        case 1:
        sText = ("Let it go, let it go");
            break;
        case 2:

        sText = ("You only need the light when its burning low");
            break;
        case 3:
        sText = ("Let it go, let it go");        
            break;

        case 4:
          sText = ("You only miss the sun when it starts to snow");                
                break;

//  continue up to case 44:

            default:
                break;
            }

            t.setText(sText);
            lineNumber++;
    }
};
```

Enjoy :)